# How can I automatize the execution of three tools in TeXstudio?

Tags: bibliographies, texstudio, biber

I want to automatize the execution of latex-biber-latex in TeXstudio as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154754). How can I do that?

Comment: Like this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154754/14757

Comment: Create a user command that runs all three components. There's an option for that in the settings.

Comment: I created a user command that runs:

    txs:///compile | txs:///biber | txs:///compile | txs:///view

and this seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to execute three different programs, use one of the latex autonomation tools, e.g. compile with

```
latexmk filename
```

instead of

```
pdflatex filename
```

and it will do everything automagically